# Ajax not working with laravel project deployment

Tags: ajax, laravel, webserver, hosting

I know this might be a broad question but i recently finished developing a laravel 5.6 app. I deployed it to a free hosting service (000webhosting) because i wanted the client to be able to preview it remotely from where they are without having to sign up for domains and hosting accounts and all that jazz.

I uploaded it by zipping my project folder and putting it in the directory of the cpanel. I put all the public files (including .htaccess) into the public_html folder and put the rest of the project into the parent directory.

Long story short, everything works fine except for ajax. Other non-ajax CRUD is functional but nothing ajax related works. It all produces 404 errors. The other non-ajax functionalities are in the same controller as the ajax methods! so i know the project is talking to itself. I have jquery library linked to on the hosted google libraries page. Is there some sort of convention that i'm missing that is limiting this functionality? do some web servers block ajax requests? It's working perfectly in my localhost wamp environment. What could i possibly look into to resolve this ajax discrepancy? If it comes to it, i'll pay for hosting, but i just want to make sure this isn't a consistent topic with many host providers where ajax needs to be specially configured or something.

github.com/maximus1127/drive ....this is the github repo. the file in question is drive/resources/views/auditor_pages/application_review.blade.php.

To login the browser, go to https://makemedrive.000webhostapp.com/ login with "aa@aa.com" pw "password". Click the instructors tab on the left, then instructor application, then view details. The "save notes", "background check/received" buttons are all the ajax features of this page and none of them work. They all produce 404 errors. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you specified ajax headers?

Comment: what is the code of error? can you post ajax example?

Comment: https://github.com/maximus1127/drive ....this is the github repo. the file in question is drive/resources/views/auditor_pages/application_review.blade.php. I have headers in the auditorDefault layout but only for xsrf tokens. One of the ajax requests saves the notes text box and the other two just run a database update with some user info. Do i need headers for those?

Comment: you need headers for every ajax request. better to put it in the <head></head> tag in <script> tag. but here everything seems ok

Comment: right, i thought things were fine and that's why i'm so confused. You can go to https://makemedrive.000webhostapp.com/ .....login with "aa@aa.com" pw "password". Click instructors tab on left, click instructor applications then view details. Try submitting/receiving the background checks or saving the notes section after typing something. it gives 404 errors

Comment: so am i missing something mate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173079/discussion-between-maximus1127-and-malkhazi-dartsmelidze).